# Saving variables in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I want to achieve that my test compares the length of a list. To get the length of my list I`m doing the following :

```
 const oldListCount = cy.get('.grid-row').its('length');
```

Later in the Test I want to compare the oldListCount with the current length.

```
 newListCount.should('be.gt',oldListCount);
```

But Cypress says that 'oldListCount' is an `[object Object]`

I also tried to work with aliases and do an encapsulated `.then` 
like so:

```
cy.get('.grid-row').its('length').then(newListCount => {
  oldLC.then(oldListCount => {
     newListCount.should('be.gt', oldListCount.toString());
    })
});
```

But either worked..
Also something worth to mention, when im log both listCounts inside the encapsulated `.then` the Count is equal, and the UI and the Cypresslogs showing me something else.

For my test it's not important that the Count is a specific number, more important is that the new Count is greater than the old one.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this will work out 
First, you need to save the old list as an alias

```
cy.get('.grid-row').as('oldList')
```

and then later in the test

```
cy.get('@oldList').its('length').then(oldLength => {
 cy.get('.grid-row').its('length').should('be.gt' , oldLength)
})
```

Comment: I tried that in my test, but when it compares the two list lengths, the Count is always equal to the current grid length. The alias doesn`t save the oldlist Count.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by creating the test with a standarized behavior.
So I have no need of saving the count, beacuase I expect always a given response, this should be more Best practice, isn`t it?